# Cross platform tool_native android app written in Java

Tags: java, android, ios, cross-platform

if I have a native android app (written in Java of course), what cross platform tool would you recommend to make it usable on iOS as well? I have been reading quite a lot about it, but most toold require code being written in html,css,js (phonegap, appcelerator etc), or for instance c# (xamarin), but which one would wrap my java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution that will work out of the box. You'll likely have to rewrite at least the UI whatever way you choose.

If you want the code to run on any mobile platform, you'll have to rewrite your code in html/css/js.

If you just want it to run on iOS, you have these options:

- If you actually want to use the very same code, use [RoboVM](http://www.robovm.com/). This will allow you to parts of the original Java code on iOS in a JVM.
- Another approach would be to automatically generate Objective C code from your Java code. This can be done using [J2ObjC](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/).

Comment: Thank you for replying, so i gotta rewrite code in for example html/css/js if i want it to be usable on ios, w7 and similar?

Comment: If you want to support all these, you will indeed have to rewrite all your code in html/css/js. If you only need iOS, then choose one of the options mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, i needed 'captain obvious'

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left.